# Automating connection to VNC with batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, vnc

I'm trying to create a batch file to automate vnc connections, this is what i came up with:

```
@echo off
:Begin
set "PASS=123"
set /p IP=Enter IP Address:
echo Connecting...
start /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\UltraVNC\" VNCVIEWER.EXE %IP%
goto Begin
```

problem is that the program comes up with a second pop up display for the password which is always 123 but i don't know how to make that automatic too, once the process is open how do i make the batch file enter the password as well automatically ?

Comment: so it'll be like

@echo off
:Begin
set "PASS=123"
set /p IP=Enter IP Address:
echo Connecting...
start /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\UltraVNC\" VNCVIEWER.EXE %IP%
echo "123" | vncviewer -autopass host:display
goto Begin


?